# 404 Not Found from redirectURL in Azure AD- OAuth/PassportJS

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, azure-active-directory, passport.js

I'm trying to implement OAuth logging from Microsoft Azure AD to my Node application with `PassportJS` and `passport-azure-ad` but everytime I send to my provider, my route https://localhost:3000/auth/openid/return returns a 404 Not found.

Everything is well setup in Azure

Here is my code:

```
passport.use(new OIDCStrategy({
        clientID: clientID,
        clientSecret: clientSecret,
        identityMetadata: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration",
        responseType: "code id_token",
        responseMode: "form_post",
        redirectUrl: "https://localhost:3000/auth/openid/return",
        passReqToCallback: false
    }, function() {
        console.log("Goin here");
    }));
```

Here are the routes:

```
router.get('/login', passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect'));

router.get('/auth/openid/return', function(req, res, next) {
res.send('callback route');
});
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

So I just changed `responseMode` property to `query` and works fine !